# Can't Display a DateTimeOffset value the way I want

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a DateTimeOffset column in my table named BarcodeTime. A sample value looks like this:

```
2013-01-20 03:34:36.8930000 -05:00
```

I'd like to display it as follows:

```
2013-01-20 03:34:36
```

I thought the following should do it:

```
CONVERT(datetime2, CONVERT(datetime2, BarcodeTime, 0), 120) as BarcodeTime
```

But this isn't working. What I get is this:  `2013-01-20 03:34:36.8930000`

Can someone show me the correct way?

Comment: Why are you converting to datetime2 at all, never mind twice? And can't you format this string *in your application*?

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(19), BarcodeTime, 120) ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the number of decimals on the `datetime2` value to 0.

```
CONVERT(datetime2(0), BarcodeTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit ugly, but if you just want to change the display output you could try:

```
SELECT LEFT(BarcodeTime, 19)
```